# Android: draw the complete content of activity on a bitmap

Tags: android

i have to take something like a screenshot in my android application. It is not a screenshot, it should be a "viewshot". It is about to render the complete content view on a bitmap.

I have found the solution to render the content view of the activity on a bitmap, but if the content view is bigger than the activity, it is only the visible part which gets drawn onto the bitmap.

Does anybody have a solution for this, or some ideas what to google?

Thanks

Comment: Provide code, that you have now, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content view is never "bigger than the activity", by definition.

The content view may be scrollable, but most scrollable things are either `AdapterViews` or use a tile mechanism (e.g., `MapView`), none of which are rendered until they are scrolled into a visible position. There is no stock way to make a "viewshot" of things that have not been rendered. You are welcome to create your own `AdapterViewShotter` that iterates over the items in the `Adapter`, captures each to a `Canvas`, and stitches the lot together into a huge image.